# Populate a cell with a different cell when selecting from a drop down

Tags: google-sheets

I have a drop down with the following: Bin Run, Single Clean, Single Clean Bagged.

I want to populate Cell G41 With contents from cell I18 when my dropdown says "Bin Run". I have this formula as follows and it seems to work.

```
=IF(G40= "Bin Run",I18)
```

but now i want to populate cell G41 with contents from cell T25 When G40 or my drop down says "Single Clean". Similarly with "Single Clean Bagged".

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you want to know how to use `if` statements with multiple possible outcomes. This is done by nesting them:

```
=if(condition 1, outcome 1, if(condition 2, outcome 2, if(...)))
```

In your case:

```
=if(G40 = "Bin Run", I18, if(G40 = "Single Clean", T25, if(G40 = "Single Clean Bagged", Z42)))
```